# ListView alternative

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, android-scrollview

I cant use a listview because I require a scrollview on the screen.  What is the best alternative in which I can pass it the .xml file I created that contains all the views that I want to be considered as a single list item.

EDIT

I cant use a listview because Listviews should never be children of ScrollViews

Comment: Why can't you use `ListView`? `ListView` is capable of showing any xml layout as its single item. Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Specifically, just put all of the items that need to be scrolled into the `ListView`.

Comment: *I cant use a listview because Listviews should never be children of ScrollViews* - that's hardly a valid argument. You should change your layout such that the `ListView` is the main scrolling container, as pointed out by @CommonsWare. That is, leverage the built-in features for header and footer views. You can even use something like a `MergeAdapter` if you have to.

Comment: ...where by `MergeAdapter` MH may be referring to mine: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: If it's still relevant, you can use one ViewGroup, give it a size larger than the screen area you want it to be, and then place it inside a ScrollView. It will be scrollable within the view port.

Answer (score 2):

Have a `LinearLayout` with the orientation that you need

In your `Activity`/`Fragment`, loop for all the items you want to add to the view (similar to getView() of the `Adapter` of a `ListView`.

In each iteration of the loop, inflate the common view layout xml file. Do what you have to do to the views inside the layout.

At the end of each iteration of the loop, add the newly inflated view to the linear layout.

In essence, you are just emulating what the `ListView` should be doing anyways.

Comment: `In essence, you are just emulating what the ListView should be doing anyways` What? `ListView` is all about `View` recycling. I don't see that happening in your approach.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Functionality of a feature always comes before performance. I'm aware that `ListView` utilizes view recycling, but that's something he has decided to forgo when he chose not to use a `ListView`. I was just coming in from the functionality point of view, thus the term "emulating". Often, emulations are not quite as efficient/effective as the real thing.